# Tkinter window freezing with pytube

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make a YouTube video download app with Tkinter, but when I click in the button to download the video with Pytube the tkinter window freeze. I know that tkinter have mainloop, but I need to know if we have a way to do the download without freeze the tkinter window.
The app is something like:

```
import tkinter as tk
from pytube import YouTube


class App():
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        self.entry = tk.Entry(master)
        self.entry.pack()
        self.entry.bind("<Return>", self.download)

    def download(self, event=None):
        YouTube(self.entry.get()).streams.first().download()


root = tk.Tk()
App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Use `threading`.

Comment: thanks, cool cloud

Answer (score 0):

All I needed for it to stop freezing was changing the file extension to mp4 when it's downloading.
By changing it, the video will be downloaded successfully and the app will respond without exception.

To do it, I simply added the `filter()` method with the file_extension argument which will be mp4 in our case. You can change it as you want.
(Line 11)

```
import tkinter as tk
from pytube import YouTube

class App():
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        self.entry = tk.Entry(master)
        self.entry.pack()
        self.entry.bind("<Return>", self.download)

    def download(self, event=None):
        YouTube(self.entry.get()).streams.filter(file_extension='mp4').first().download()


root = tk.Tk()
App(root)
root.mainloop()
```